# Setting up docker-compose.yml to run celery worker and celery beat for a django project with redis as broker

Tags: python, django, celery, docker-compose

I have setup django project using django cookiecutter. The project scaffolding is excellent. I also opted to use docker along with it. Now I am struggling with getting celery v4.0.x working in the whole setup.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=application


  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=application
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /tmp/
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env
    restart:
      - "on-failure"


  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/nginx/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
    links:
      - django
    volumes_from:
      - django


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis


  celeryworker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    env_file: ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: celery -A application.taskapp worker -l INFO
    restart: "on-failure"


  celerybeat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    env_file: ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: celery -A application.taskapp beat -l INFO
```

Quite honestly I feel there seems to be some tiny issue with config for celerybeat/celeryworker service. It would be nice if someone can point it out.

**Update:**

When I execute the command to run the containers, I get an error saying that application could not be found

**Update**

This is the new compose file which ironed out few errors in my compose. Somewhere along the way of getting it all working I also came across thread where someone had mentioned that ordering of the services mattered as well. So in the new version, django is placed first.

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:

  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /tmp/
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=application
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env


  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=application
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:6379:6379"
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env


  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/nginx/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
    links:
      - django
    volumes_from:
      - django


  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    command: "celery -A application.taskapp worker --loglevel INFO --uid taskmaster"
```

Comment: What is the actual issue you're running into? Why can't you get it working, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Bono, my bad just check the update

Comment: Could you post the error itself? :)

Comment: @Bono I got it fixed. I will update what I did with changes to my docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Bono: how did you fixed it ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza celery requires links to redis container as well in case you are using it as a broker. I will just put my update docker-compose file contents.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza correction to my last comment. What I meant was "celery requires links to redis container as well in case you are using it as a broker and it needs to be exposed via ports. I will just put my updated docker-compose file contents in the original question."

Comment: @AvinashRaj you probably have something else running on port 8000. Check what is running on port 8000 or else you can share your compose file.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the same tech stack . This works fine for me.
docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--port", "${REDIS_PORT}", "--appendonly", "yes","--maxmemory", "1gb", "--maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lru"]
    ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}"
    volumes:
        - .:/redis.conf
    networks:
        - pipeline-net

celery-worker:
    build:
    context: ./app
    container_name: celery-worker
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A celery_app.celery worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/app/worker
    links:
    - redis
    depends_on:
    - redis
    networks:
    - pipeline-net

celery-beat:
    build:
    context: ./app
    container_name: celery-beat
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A celery_app.celery beat --loglevel=info
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/app/beat
    links:
    - celery-worker
    - redis
    depends_on:
    - celery-worker
    - redis
    networks:
    - pipeline-net

flower:
    image: mher/flower
    container_name: flower
    environment:
    - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379
    - FLOWER_PORT=8888
    ports:
    - 8888:8888
    links:
    - redis
    - celery-worker
    - celery-beat
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - celery-worker
    - celery-beat
    networks:
    - pipeline-net
```